# bootstrap table-striped in multiple tbody with doubled tr

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I was simple table and I used bootstrap and classes table and table-striped. It works well.

```
<h3>Old table</h3>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Brand</th><th>Model</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Audi</td><td>A1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Audi</td><td>A2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Audi</td><td>A3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Audi</td><td>A4</td></tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

But now I have to complicate my table and use multiple tbody in tabled element (each tbody has two tr element). So bootstrap class table-striped does not work. **There is any way to do it in bootstrap?** The rows with cars should be *table-striped* but comment rows not.

```
<h3>Current table</h3>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Brand</th><th>Model</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Audi</td><td>A1</td></tr>
        <tr class="comment"><td colspan="2">Comment...</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Audi</td><td>A2</td></tr>
        <tr class="comment hide"><td colspan="2">Comment...</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Audi</td><td>A3</td></tr>
        <tr class="comment"><td colspan="2">Comment...</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Audi</td><td>A4</td></tr>
        <tr class="comment hide"><td colspan="2">Comment...</td></tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

## [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ptxZbeHgHeE9tuCcx6en?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

The work around for bootstrap would be much more complicated than just putting in your own custom classes. The [bootstrap source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/tables.less) for `table-striped` simply makes all odd rows the different color. That means that you're likely going to getting way further in depth and causing yourself way more trouble if you try to have bootstrap do it for you versus just putting in the classes yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tbody').parents('.fixed-table-container').find('tr:even').addClass( 'even' );

.even { background: #f9f9f9; }
```

And in bootstrap.min.css find --> `.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd){background-color:#f9f9f9}` replace --> `.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd){background-color:none}`

Comment: fixed-table-container corresponds to the div before table